# Mongoose enum Validation on String Arrays?

Tags: arrays, string, validation, enums, mongoose

Is it possible to use `enum` validation on `type: [String]`?

Example:

```
var permitted = ['1','2','3'];

var exampleSchema = new Schema({
    factors: {
            type: [String],
            enum: permitted,
            required: "Please specify at least one factor."
    }
});
```

I would have expected that `factors` would only be able to contain the values in `permitted`.

Answer (score 59):

This is working fine for me (`mongoose@4.1.8`)

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  factors: [{type: String, enum: ['1', '2', '3'], required: ...}] 
  ...
})
```

Note I'm using an Array of Objects

Comment: I didn't know about this feature! Cool :)

Comment: Can I do something like this to create array of string enums rather than creating array of objects?



roles: { 
    type: [{ type: String, enum: [ 'resident', 'distributor', 'company', 'moderator', 'admin' ] }],
    default: 'resident'
}

Comment: @Janusz01 Yes this also fine!

Answer (score 13):

As of `mongoose` version `5.0.6` and higher, the OP issue now works!

```
 factors: {
            type: [String],
            enum: permitted,
            required: "Please specify at least one factor."
    }
```

Reference

> https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6204#issuecomment-374690551

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose before version 4.0 didn't support validation on Schema static methods like `.update`, `.findByIdAndUpdate`, `.findOneAndUpdate`.

But it supports on instance method `document.save()`.

So, either use `document.save()` for inbuilt initiating  validation
or this `{ runValidators: true }` with methods like `.update`, `.findByIdAndUpdate`, `.findOneAndUpdate`.

reference:
[Mongoose .update() does not trigger validation checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614568/mongoose-update-does-not-trigger-validation-checking)

Comment: mongoose@6.2.10 also does not support this and it working in Doc.save only

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
let inventory_type_enum = ["goods", "services"];

 inventory_type: {
    type: String,
    enum: inventory_type_enum,
    validate: {
      //  validator: (inventory_type) => !inventory_type.enum.includes(inventory_type),
        validator: (inventory_type) => inventory_type_enum.includes(inventory_type),
        message: languages('general_merchandise_model','inventory_type')
    },
      required : [true, languages('general_merchandise_model','inventory_type_required')],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have enuns or you have object enuns

```
brand: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: Object.values(TypeBrandEnum)
  },
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation. (Spending some time on spell-checking is NOT required, but would improve the general impression.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
{
 factors: [
    {
      type: [String],
      enum: ['1', '2', '3'],
    },
  ],
}
```