# Mongoose .update() does not trigger validation checking

Tags: mongoose

I can set values beyond the enum array and I do not know why mongoose not validate the value, am I do update the enum in wrong way?

my code:

```
var OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
status:{type:String,enum:['created','shipped','confirmed']},
)};

var changeOrderStatus = function(shopId,orderId,status,callback){

    Order.update({_id:orderId,shop:shopId},{$set:{status:status}},{upsert:false},
        function(err){

            console.log(err);
            callback(err);

    })
}
```

The **status** enum should only have value for the three:['created','shipped','confirmed']

but I could do:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mongoose before version 4.0 didn't support validation on Schema static methods like `.update`, `.findByIdAndUpdate`, `.findOneAndUpdate`.

But it supports on instance method `document.save()`

So first you need to find an order and then change property you want and call `.save()`. Like this:

```
Order.findOne({ _id: orderId, shop: shopId }, function(err, order) {
  order.status = 'foo';
  order.save(function(err, savedOrder) {
    // ERROR HERE
  })
})
```

If you use Mongoose 4.0 it supports the validation in `Schema.update` of the fields of `$set` and `$unset` operators when you include the `runValidators: true` option in the update call.

So your updating will look like this:

```
Order.update(
  { _id: orderId, shop: shopId },
  { $set: { status: status }},
  { upsert: true, runValidators: true }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
}
```